# pandas unstacking from long to wide format

Tags: python, pandas

This will likely get marked as a duplicate but I can't seem to solve the issue despite trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537317/pandas-long-to-wide-multicolumn-reshaping) answer. The problem is I have data which are in long format and require a new row for each value of `subject` and `beta` should expand to be `A_i_beta`, `A_j_beta`... etc. There are many more values in my actual dataset.

I made a small example of my data, ran the below code, and it was successful. But when I scaled it up to my actual dataset I get an error. Here are my example data and code:

```
subject name    region  xyz beta
1   A   i   54 -52 8    0.149812742
1   B   i   54 -52 8    1.23882482
2   A   i   54 -52 8    -1.150757713
2   B   i   54 -52 8    -0.635049755
1   A   j   16 -66 58   2.452675111
1   B   j   16 -66 58   1.193138828
2   A   j   16 -66 58   -1.063844842
2   B   j   16 -66 58   -0.69318946

df = df.drop('xyz', axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['subject', 'name', 'region'])
df = df.unstack()
df.columns = [f'{i[0]}_{i[1]}' for i in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)

   subject name    beta_i    beta_j
0        1    A  0.149813  2.452675
1        1    B  1.238825  1.193139
2        2    A -1.150758 -1.063845
3        2    B -0.635050 -0.693189
```

So that works. But then when I apply it to my actual dataset, I get the following error:

```
df = df.set_index(['subject', 'name', 'region'])
df = df.unstack()

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

I am not really sure where to go from here with this.

Comment: `unstack` doesn't allow duplicated index. You need to use `pivot_table` and handle duplicated values

Comment: what specifically is it that is causing this problem though? because it worked in the example data and that seems to have duplicated values in the columns that get set as index.

Comment: You don't have duplicates in your example. You do within a level of your multiindex, but each row has a unique combination of `'subject'`, `'name'`, `'region'`.